# Elasticsearch: build binary mask based on filter

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I've got ES index **products** with data like this (simplified version, there are about 20 fields actually):

```
{_id: 1, _score: 1, color: red, size: S}
{_id: 2, _score: 1, color: red, size: M}
{_id: 3, _score: 1, color: red, size: L}
{_id: 4, _score: 1, color: blue, size: S}
{_id: 5, _score: 1, color: blue, size: M}
{_id: 6, _score: 1, color: blue, size: L}
```

I want to filter products by attributes (color and size) but I need all of them be presented in results, the filter condition should affect only scores. Examples:

```
Query: color == red
Result:
{_id: 1, _score: 1}
{_id: 2, _score: 1}
{_id: 3, _score: 1}
{_id: 4, _score: 0}
{_id: 5, _score: 0}
{_id: 6, _score: 0}

Query: size == M
Result:
{_id: 1, _score: 0}
{_id: 2, _score: 1}
{_id: 3, _score: 0}
{_id: 4, _score: 0}
{_id: 5, _score: 1}
{_id: 6, _score: 0}

Query: color == red && size == M
Result:
{_id: 1, _score: 0}
{_id: 2, _score: 1}
{_id: 3, _score: 0}
{_id: 4, _score: 0}
{_id: 5, _score: 0}
{_id: 6, _score: 0}
```

Any ideas how can I achieve that? Does it look like work for elasticsearch? Maybe I should consider to switch some other store/database.
ES version is 1.7.5

Comment: What you are looking for are the term and bool queries in the latest version, not sure about 1.7.5

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I don't see the way how to stop ES discard documents that do no match query. I can construct my filter clause as "query" -> "bool" -> "must" -> list of terms .. but in that case how to get documents that does not satisfied ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your use case is but this is not something I would recommend that you do trying to fix your relevancy score. Here is an example for one of the cases and there are multiple ways of doing this

```
POST /_search
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
               "constant_score":{
                  "filter":{
                     "term":{
                        "color":"red"
                     }
                  },
                  "boost":1
               }
            },
            {
               "bool":{
                  "must_not":{
                     "term":{
                        "color":"red"
                     }
                  },
                  "boost":0
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

and the result is

```
{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 6,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "color": "red",
                    "size": "M"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "color": "red",
                    "size": "S"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "color": "red",
                    "size": "L"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "5",
                "_score": 0,
                "_source": {
                    "color": "blue",
                    "size": "M"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 0,
                "_source": {
                    "color": "blue",
                    "size": "S"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "6",
                "_score": 0,
                "_source": {
                    "color": "blue",
                    "size": "L"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```